# PHP login to users account as admin

Tags: php, authentication, admin

I have a users based site (PHP).

When a user is created, a random password is generated and they have the ability to change it.
The password is saved using

```
password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

At login i use password_verify() to check the password and log them in to the site.

The site has an Admin Panel (in different session) and i want to give the Admin the possibility to login users without knowing their password.

I want to know what is the safest way to do so, prefer without 'master password'.

The site :

www.my-site.com

The admin panel :

www.my-site.com/admin/

Comment: store encrypted password in cookie with other safe encryption method and post on login without asking for password, decrypt your encrypted password before passing to password_verify (save password after first successful login)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware login to user

Comment: Your answer is unclear. It might be a language issue. The meaning of "to login users" differs from "login to users", which sounds more like "login as users".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want the admin to login to the user as if the user login ,sorry for clearance, better ?

Comment: Yes, I think you mean that the administrator can log in, as an user of the system, without knowing the user's password. There's far to little information in your question to answer it and be sure the answer contains 'the safest way' to do it. It all depends on the relation between the Admin Panel and the users based site.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i edited the question with the relation

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do so would be simply bypassing auth if logged in as admin.
For example, let's say that you have `users.php` script that lists all users. It also gives you "admin" cookie when logged in as admin.
There you can add button Manage/Panel/anything else, which will take you to `admin.php` with GET parameter, for example, `?user=someone`. Script will check if you have that "admin" cookie, and if you do, will open admin panel.
If you don't have this cookie, it will throw 403 or anything you want.